# functional component set useState in conditional function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If you set useState variable in function where is condition like "if statement" it's ok? I read that you shouldn't use hook's in conditions but is it also true for setting the state? Example will show what i mean. If I cant do like this how can I set it right way if I have multiple variables and if conditions. Please help me thanks

I'm aware of this: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation
but I have some doubts

```
import React, { useState} from "react";

const MoreInfo = () => {

const [more_info, setMore_info] = useState("test");

const handleExpand = (event) => {
        if (icon_expand === 'expand_more') {
        setMore_info("test2");  // is this ok in if?
      }
}

  return (
 <IconButton onClick={handleExpand}>
);
};

export default MoreInfo;
```

Comment: You can use the method `setMore_info` where ever you like. It's just the hook method invocation that should be at the top of your method.

Comment: The important thing is that the `useState` hook calls are made in the same order every time, because they're matched to the values they control by index (see https://overreacted.io/why-do-hooks-rely-on-call-order/). There is no problem with calling the setter function inside a conditional.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The hook is `useState`. And the rules apply for that call only (and any other hook's call that might be using, and custom hooks, like `useSomething`).

The `setState` call is not a hook call. You're calling a method that was returned from a hook call. Infact React guarantees that the `setState` reference doesn't change between renders.

Rules of hooks:

> Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
>
> Only Call Hooks from React Functions

The following article might help you understand why these rules exist. It gives a visual explanation of hooks under the hood.

https://medium.com/@ryardley/react-hooks-not-magic-just-arrays-cd4f1857236e

```js
function App() {
  
  // THE useState CALL SHOULD BE ON TOP LEVEL
  // CAN'T BE CALLED INSIDE ANY CONDITIONALS
  const [myState,setMyState] = React.useState(0); 
  
  // THE setState CALLS CAN BE ANYWHERE
  function changeCounter(value) {
    if (value === 'increment') {
      setMyState((prevState) => prevState + 1);
    }
    else if (value === 'decrement') {
      setMyState((prevState) => prevState - 1);
    }
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Counter: {myState}</div>
      <button onClick={() => changeCounter('increment')}>
        +
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => changeCounter('decrement')}>
        -
      </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Can you suggest a way to import setMyState variable as a prop on another react component